# Firebase and admod integration error

Tags: firebase, admob, firebase-analytics

As we all are seeing to following screen in admod to encourage more dev to add admob faster to firebase.
[image]

I am seeing follwoing screen where it suppose to link admob ads to firebase to share some analytics. I guess. 
[image: error screen]

I am receiving error on this page from last 5 days. First I thought may be something is not synced up yet. but that does not seem the case. It read my project name right which are available on firebase correctly. Drop down list is fully populated with all the project that are available in firebase. 
Is anyone else also having the same problem.

Plus I also want to take opportunity to ask if going forward I would be managing my ads in firebase or this setup is just to share analytics.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check/confirm the following:

- You're using the same email address for both AdMob and Firebase
- The Firebase project you're linking to hasn't been deleted (you can verify this by checking if you can see the project on the [Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com))

If the above steps do not help, file an issue with [Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/). Thanks!